# Error: canceled due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to download a zip from a url but RNFetchBlob tells me that I have a previous response pending and crashes the application.

This is the function where i call fetch

```
  const downloadFile = async () => {
  const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

  const response = await RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true,
    appendExt: 'zip',
    path: dirs.DownloadDir + '/files/icons.zip',
    addAndroidDownloads: {
      title: dirs.DownloadDir + '/files/icons.zip',
      description: `Download ${dirs.DownloadDir + '/files/icons.zip'}`,
      useDownloadManager: false,
      notification: false,
    },
  }).fetch('GET', BASE_URL + 'iconos');

  console.log(response.path());
  console.log(response);
  return response;
};
```

Here i check the permission

```
const checkPermission = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const response = await downloadFile();
    return response;
  } else {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Storage Permission Required',
          message: 'Application needs access to your storage to download File',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // Start downloading
        const response = await downloadFile();
        console.log('Storage Permission Granted.');
        return response;
      } else {
        // If permission denied then show alert
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Storage Permission Not Granted');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // To handle permission related exception
      console.log('++++' + err);
    }
  }
};
```

And this is my redux reducer

```
export const getIcons = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await checkPermission();
      dispatch(getResponseSuccess(response));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(getResponseFailure());
    }
  };
};
```

When the app execute downloadFile inside checkPermission cath and error that saids

> ++++Error: canceled due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please
> call response.close()

Comment: did you got any workaround?